# Xcode is an application downloaded from the Internet.

Tags: xcode

I'm new to Mac. I downloaded XCode_4.5.dmg. When I double click it, it opens a new window and shows a single file - XCode. When I double click that, I get a warning:
"Xcode is an application downloaded from the Internet. Are you sure you want to open it?"

I guess I didn't install XCode properly. So I tried Control + Click but there isn't any option to install. So, how do I install it?

Thanks

Comment: Wow. A question that is tagged Xcode and **is about Xcode.**. +1 for that.

Comment: it's off topic, ask that on http://apple.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't worry about the warning message if you downloaded the DMG file from a safe place, such as [Apple Connect](http://connect.apple.com). The message is from Mac OS X, which warns you to confirm that you really want to open the file.

After you opened the DMG file, you need to drag the Xcode app bundle into the Applications folder of you Mac.

An easier way to install Xcode is to use **App Store**. App Store is available on Lion (10.7), Mountain Lion (10.8) and some late revisions of Snow Leopard (10.6).

Answer (score 2):

The best way to install XCode is to use the Mac App Store. That will handle the installation and setup for you, as well as handle your updates.

Answer (score 0):

That is common message on Mac.  For all the programs that are downloaded, when you run it for the first time, you will see the message. You click on Ok and the message won't be shown again.

Now what you want to actually do is drag the XCode icon from inside the .dmg to Applications folder (You can see it in the taskbar on side or bottom or left, depending on how you have your system configured.  It will take a few min to get the file unzipped and moved to Applications. Then when you click on the Applications, XCode should be there. Of course, for the first time clicking on it, Mac will ask the same question : 'XCode is an application downloaded from interenet....' Say ok and you are set. Good luck!